# AWS Lambda: Parameter validation failed

Tags: parameters, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, http-method

I'm trying to run the following code to write into dynamodb via a POST method but getting an error:

```
{
    "httpMethod":"POST",
    "body": {
        "TableName":"LamdaTest",
        "Item":{
            "ID":"1",
            "Name":"Foobar"

        }
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Item.ID, value: 1, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>\nInvalid type for parameter Item.Name, value: Foobar, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing it like this, as a dictionary (from the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item)):

```
{
    "httpMethod":"POST",
    "body": {
        TableName="LamdaTest",
        Item={
            "ID": {"N":"1"},
            "Name": {"S":"Foobar"}
        }
    }
}
```